# Idiomatic adding to path-like variable

Tags: python, string, path

What's a good way to add an entry to a `PATH`-like variable in Python?

It needs to be able to deal with a non-existing initial value - e.g. when adding an entry `/new` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, it needs to set it to `/oldvalue:/new` if its previous value was `/oldvalue`, or just to `/new` if its previous value was empty or `os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']` didn't exist.

What I have is very clunky:

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = os.pathsep.join(
    [x for x in filter(None, os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '').split(os.pathsep))]
    + ['/new']
)
```

I was hoping to find something in [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), but that doesn't even mention the pathsep at all (despite the [docs for `os.pathsep`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.pathsep) saying it should).

Comment: `os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH","")+os.pathsep+"/new/path"` would work i think ...

Comment: The docs just say that `os.pathsep` is "Also available via os.path", and it is (`os.path.pathsep`).

Comment: @larsks - I don't see `pathsep` in the docs anywhere at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html - is it super-sekrit?

Comment: It's not in the docs for `os.path`, but it is available as `os.path.pathsep`.

Comment: Okay, thanks @larsks - I take that to mean it's either deprecated (or past deprecation) or not ready for use yet.

Comment: @JoranBeasley - that sort of works, but it sticks an extra `pathsep` at the beginning when `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is previously unset, which is behavior I don't like.

Comment: then just call `.strip(os.pathsep)` ... i didnt bother because it doesnt actually affect anything with the extra leading ;

Comment: So then it looks like `os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = (os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH","")+os.pathsep+"/new/path").strip(os.pathsep)` is the best recommendation, which is pretty ugly.  Something like `os.environ.addpath('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '/new/path', where='end')` would sure be nicer and have a lot less repetition, and a lot less fiddling with the underlying implementation details.